# Parse error unexpected ":" Works fine in localhost

Tags: php

I have a PHP application with me, which was done by myself and a few of us. I have not coded much, but it worked well in the `localhost`. When I tried to upload it in our university web server, I had got this error.

> Parse error unexpected `:`

This happened on this line. So I believe that PHP has to do something with respect to the previous line too. So I am adding the previous and next lines:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $page = $_GET["page"] ?: "index"; // Error in this line!
```

The funny part is, this works on my WAMP Server locally, but it doesn't work in the university server. Is there any issue with the code?

Comment: Your running a newer version localy - the `?:` syntax is new

Comment: What's the PHP version locally and in the server?

Comment: I am using PHP 5.4 in WAMP Server. University uses 5.2.12.

Comment: you have to upgrade it to 5.3

Comment: @Bak Can't upgrade university servers.

Comment: Talk to the admins. If they don't hear there is a need for an update, they won't do anything. Having such an outdated PHP version will create plenty of problems when using current PHP software, not only related to security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the PHP in your University Web Server is very old or older than **5.3**. This is a shorthand ternary operator and is supported by PHP versions 5.3 and above.

**Workaround**

```
$page = $_GET["page"] ? $_GET["page"] : "index";
```

**Update:** To remove the warning, where `$_GET["page"]` is not set, you can use:

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : "index"; // Checks if $_GET["page"] exists, and then assigns it.
```

PHP 7 will allow to use this short syntax:

```
$page = $_GET["page"] ?? "index";
```

From the docs:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Comment: The workaround worked. But I have an issue. I am sometimes getting `Warning` in the `index` page alone. Is there anything that you can help me with?

Comment: That could be because `$_GET["page"]` is not set. You can override it with an `@` in front of it.

Comment: Don't suppress errors, it's bad practice! Rather, do a test if the field is set `(isset($_GET['page'])) ? //do stuff : //do other stuff `

Comment: @AlanMachado I have included that in my comment in the line. Did you see that? `:)`

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I was making a suggestion, also!

Comment: @AlanMachado LoL... Before you have added the comment, I have written both buddy. I know that's wrong and dangerous too! `:)` Check my answer, the second line! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

I suggest that your university should update their servers to a supported version of PHP

Comment: Can't upgrade the university servers, sorry. But thanks, I got a workaround from Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the version of PHP.

Maybe your PHP version local is higher than in your university server.

You must see in which version from PHP `?:` works

Answer (score -1):

If the syntax does not work on your server it might be that "short tags" are disabled in your PHP ini file.

Comment: Short tags are enabled.